# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'awsgi' in flask app

Tags: flask, python-3.7

Below is my 'pip freeze requirements.txt' on the 3rd line, aws-wsgi is installed not sure why am getting the error:
**ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'awsgi'** I am using the module documented here https://pypi.org/project/aws-wsgi/ 
Any help will be appreciated. 
Thanks

- aniso8601==8.0.0
- attrs==19.3.0
- aws-wsgi==0.2.6
- boto3==1.13.26
- botocore==1.16.26
- certifi==2020.4.5.2
- chardet==3.0.4
- click==7.1.2
- cognitojwt==1.2.2
- docutils==0.15.2
- ecdsa==0.15
- Flask==1.1.2
- flask-restx==0.2.0
- idna==2.9
- importlib-metadata==1.6.1
- itsdangerous==1.1.0
- Jinja2==2.11.2
- jmespath==0.10.0
- jsonschema==3.2.0
- MarkupSafe==1.1.1
- pyasn1==0.4.8
- pyrsistent==0.16.0
- python-dateutil==2.8.1
- python-jose==3.1.0
- pytz==2020.1
- requests==2.23.0
- rsa==4.1
- s3transfer==0.3.3
- six==1.15.0
- urllib3==1.25.9
- Werkzeug==1.0.1
- zipp==3.1.0-

Comment: Could you include your code that shows your imports?

Answer (score 0):

This was due to an error in my local environment. Apparently, I needed to activate virtual environment in my opened Visual Studio Code. I was only focusing on my my terminal.

I solved it by activating the virtual environment in my Visual Studio Code as well.